# MS Access 2013 form [control source] lookup field on another table

Tags: database, forms, ms-access-2013

I feel like I am missing a fundamentally easy process in Access right now.

I have 2 tables with different information on them. `Table1` is client info `Table2` is client orders. The primary key linking these two tables is the `client_id`. I made a form to input data into `Form2`. The form works and I can easily submit data to `Form2` but I would like to add a read-only text box beside the `client_id` field that will display the customers first and last name (stored on `Table1`) to show the user that the `client_id` was typed in correctly. Am I going about this the wrong way or am I just missing something? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AfterUpdate` event of the `client_id` field, use [`DLookup`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) to lookup the client name, and set the value of an unbound, locked textbox to the name.

You can also fetch two fields into one expression:

```
Me.txtClientName = DLookup("[FirstName] & ' ' & [LastName]", _ 
                   "Clients", "client_id = " & Me.client_id)
```

Comment: After posting this I found what I was doing wrong but honestly this helps even more! thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of the & function.